# Storing PHP variable into JavaScript variable in a For loop

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I know how to pass a PHP variable into JavaScript variable one by one, but now I wish to pass a bunch of variable in a For loop and I just stuck.

```
<?php
        $m = new MongoClient();
        $db = $m->data_from_tweeter;
        $collection = $db->output;
        $cursor = $collection->find();
        foreach($cursor as $document){
            echo $document['place'] ;
            echo $document['fir'];
            echo $document['sec'];
        }
?>
```

I want to store 'place' as a String variable, 'fir' and 'sec' as two Num variables, and make them look like:

```
var num_1 {
    some_place : some_fir,
    some_place : some_fir,
    some_place : some_fir,
    ....
}
```

and

```
var num_2 {
    some_place : some_sec,
    some_place : some_sec,
    some_place : some_sec,
    ....
}
```

How can I make it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Object keys can't be the same in the same object. Change your object structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet might help get you started:

```
$num_1 = "var num_1 = {\n";
$num_2 = "var num_2 = {\n";
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
        $num_1 .= "    {$document['place']} : {$document['fir']},\n";
        $num_2 .= "    {$document['place']} : {$document['sec']},\n";
}  
$num_1 .= "};\n";
$num_2 .= "};\n";

echo $num_1;
echo $num_2;
```

Comment: Thanks! Make sense a lot to me!

Answer (score 1):

if $document['fir'] and $document['sec'] are array .You can do like this

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->data_from_tweeter;
$collection = $db->output;
$cursor = $collection->find();
$num1=array();
$num2=array();
foreach($cursor as $document){
    echo $document['place'] ;
    $num1 = json_encode ($document['fir']);
    $num2 = json_encode ($document['sec']);
}
?>
```

You can use a JSON string as a object for javascript

```
var num_1  = <?php echo $num1;?>
var num_2  = <?php echo $num2;?>
```